# Finding all disconnected subgraphs in a graph

Tags: java, algorithm, graph, subgraph

I have a graph which contains an unknown number of disconnected subgraphs. What's a good algorithm (or Java library) to find them all?

Comment: Thank you all, especially MAK and Agor. I'm going to start with a flood fill and breadth first search then take it from there.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is generally called a [Flood Fill](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill). It is up to you whether you traverse the graph through a BFS or a DFS.

Basically you take an unlabeled (AKA uncoloured) node and assign a new label to it. You assign the same label to all nodes adjacent to that one, and so on to all nodes that are reachable from that node.

When no more reachable nodes can be labeled, you start over by picking another unlabeled node. Notice that the fact that this new node is unlabeled implies that it is not reachable from our earlier node and is thus in a different disconnected component.

When there are no more unlabeled nodes, the number of distinct labels you had to use is the number of components of the graph. The label for each node tells you which node is part of which component.

Comment: Thanks, this a great place to start and a very practical answer.

Answer (score 29):

Not a Java implementation but perhaps it will be useful for someone, here is how to do it in Python:

```py
import networkx as nx
g = nx.Graph()
# add nodes/edges to graph

d = list(nx.connected_components(g)) 
# d contains disconnected subgraphs
# d[0] contains the biggest subgraph
```

More information [here](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.components.connected_components.html#networkx.algorithms.components.connected_components).

Answer (score 12):

There are many facets of this question that are not fully explained, so I'm going to give a somewhat exhaustive answer. My tendency to post walls-of-text notwithstanding. :/ Note also that I'm assuming this is a homework question or self-education question, so I'm not going to give a straight-up answer.

The two basic algorithms for detecting connectivity of a graph is [Depth First Search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) and [Breadth First Search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search). Those are really the 2 starting points you want to look at. Both will get you to the solution, but in different ways, and its hard to argue which is "better" without considering some pretty in-depth aspects of the problem. But let's move on.

As I mentioned before, you left out some important details, and I'll touch upon some possibilities here.

Is your graph directed or undirected? and do you consider connectivity in the "strong" sense (in which case, see oggy's answer), or connectivity in the "weak" sense? Depending on your answer, you will have to approach your algorithm in a subtly different way. Note that, for an undirected graph, weak and strong connectivity are equivalent, so that's nice. But you'll have to keep the structure of the graph in mind regardless, while implementing or finding an algorithm.

Furthermore, there is the question of what you mean by "finding the subgraphs" (paraphrase). Usually graph connectivity is a decision problem -- simply "there is one connected graph" or "there are two or more sub-graphs (aka, it's disconnected)". Having an algorithm for that requires the least amount of bookwork, which is nice. :) The next step up would be the *count* of graphs, literally the number of them, and that bookwork is also not so bad. Penultimately, you may want a list of nodes in each sub-graph. Lastly, you may want to literally copy out the sub-graphs, edges and all (so the return type would be a list of graphs, I suppose, with an implied invariant that each graph is connected). None of these different result-types would require a different algorithm, but *will certainly* require a different approach to the bookwork.

All of this may seem like a ridiculous amount of overkill for what is a pretty basic question, but I thought I'd just highlight all of the aspects involved in even such a simple graph question. As a sort of cliffhanger, note how none of this even yet touches upon runtime or memory usage! :)
- Agor

Comment: Thanks, this is a self-education question and I appreciate the detail, I value your bringing the assumptions I made to light.

I'm working with undirected graphs and my goal to produce a method which takes one graph and returns a collection of all the subgraphs.

Answer (score 3):

[JGraphT](http://jgrapht.sourceforge.net/) is a nice open source graphing library licensed under the LGPL license.  I have used it in the past to deal with graphs and detecting cycles within the graphs.  It is also fairly easy to use, and you can use [JGraph](http://www.jgraph.com/) to visualize the graphs.

Comment: ConnectivityInspector class should be what is needed.

Comment: Having never had to do much other than prove existence/non-existence of cycles, I was not sure, so I simply linked to the library - it has been pretty solid for our project.

Answer (score 2):

What about a breadth first search to find all connected nodes?  Once you have the list of connected nodes, you subtract this list from the list of all nodes.  You end up with a list of disconnected nodes

Comment: Wow this was exactly what I needed. It's the fastest if you're not interested in specific subgraph segmentation etc. The only question is where to start the search in the graph, but that depends on the specific graph ofc.

Answer (score 2):

I probably should have found a standard algorithm ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_(graph_theory)) has some suggestions), but I came up with this on my own and it worked well for my purposes. My C# implementation takes a couple seconds to process a graph with 40,000 nodes and 44,000 edges to find 160 subgraphs and 20,000 unconnected nodes. I used a HashSet to store each subgraph group, so testing group membership is approximately O(1), and the overall algorithm becomes O(E*C) where E is the number of edges and C is the number of connected components in the graph. Wikipedia mentions an O(N) algorithm, linear in the number of nodes, so I'm sure mine is not maximally efficient, but it was plenty fast for my application. (Edit: I'm also glossing over the cost of merging groups, so don't put too much weight on my complexity analysis.)

Logic:

```
For each edge A->B
  If A is in a group and B is not, add B to group A
  If A is not in a group and B is, add A to group B
  If A and B are in different groups, merge the groups
  If neither A or B is in a group, create new group containing A and B
```

Pseudocode:

```
graph = {nodes, edges}
groups = {}
foreach edge A->B in graph.edges:
    groupA = findgroup(A)
    groupB = findgroup(B)
    if (groupA && !groupB)
        groupA.add(B)
    elif (!groupA && groupB)
        groupB.add(A)
    elif (groupA && groupB)
        if (groupA != groupB)
            groupA.union(groupB)
            groups.delete(groupB)
    else
        groups.add({A,B})
```

```
findgroup(node):
    for group in groups:
        if group.contains(node):
            return group
    return null
```

Note that this won't capture any nodes that aren't involved in edges. For my particular purposes this was fine. If you want to get all the single-node groups you can do a final pass:

```
foreach node in graph.nodes:
    group = findgroup(node)
    if !group:
        groups.add({node})
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you want to find all the (strongly) connected components? For that you can use [Tarjan's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarjan's_strongly_connected_components_algorithm) (a variant of DFS)

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar problem where I wanted all the weakly connected subgraphs of a directed graph.  I blogged about it [here](http://harschware.blogspot.com/2010/02/converting-disconnected-graphs-to.html).  I used the [JUNG](http://jung.sourceforge.net/) API and compare two approaches.  My first approach could be used as a template to solve your problem.