# Filling a grid with unknown shapes

Tags: arrays, algorithm, dictionary, grid, flood-fill

As an input i am giving 2D grid of 0´s with few -1 positions indicating  places that can not be filled and blueprint of some shapes (as in Tetris game)

```
 ex. of grid              ex. of shapes

 0  0  0  0  0  0  0        1 1 1     2 2 2     3 3
-1  0  0  0  0  0  0        1           2
-1  0  0  0  0  0  0        1
 0  0  0  0  0 -1  0
 0  0  0 -1  0  0  0
```

Algorithm should output 
the grid filled with given shapes always having to use all of them once
I can rotate the shapes and i should always be given grid and shapes that is possible to fill.
 I looked into algorithms like flood fill algorithm but i do not really see a way of using it here. Is it possible to do it differently than brute forcing through?

Comment: There is no efficient solution for these problems with generic shapes. How big is the grid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my thought on how I go about solving this:

For each shape it seems there are 4 possible types ( including the original )
for example:

```
1 1 1          1    1 1 1    1
1       ->     1        1    1
1          1 1 1,       1,   1 1 1
```

Now lets say there are `s` number of shapes, then there are `4s` total shapes.

Take a combination out of `4s` shapes and form a figure like:

```
  2
1 2 2
1 2 3 3
1 1 1
```

or

```
1 1 1
1 2 3 3
1 2 2
  2
```

or

```
1 1 1 3 3
1 2 2 2
1   2
```

or

any such figure out of `(4s)^2 = 16s^2` possibilities.

Actually it is more than `16s^2`, because it is not just concatenation of shapes, you need to greedily look for vacant spaces and try to fit in there. :(

Now you have a figure in your hand, look for the same shape in your grid.

So for example to look for

```
1 1 1
1 2 3 3
1 2 2
  2
```

I would look for

```
0 0 0
0 0 0 0
0 0 0
  0
```

in the original grid.

Then this seems to be a problem of finding that figure in the original matrix.

Also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17149236/anyone-knows-an-algorithm-for-finding-shapes-in-2d-arrays) which is a similar question but not exactly the same, about finding shapes.